# Android espresso edittext auto capitalize

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am using espresso to test an `editText`. The problem is that when I run `onView(withId(R.id.titleInput)).perform(typeText("Hello World"));` The word "World" is sometimes in capital, sometimes in lowercase. How can I force the keyboard to capitalize/disable it?

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line in your XML edittext

```
android:textAllCaps="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I eventually found an answer helpful to me, it might help someone else in the future, what worked for me was in the keyboard, the keyboard on the emulator had auto capitalization on and for some reason it will auto capitalize the second word, turning that feature off on the keyboard seemed to solve my problem